# Vertex Groups transform

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have vertex groups in my model that is bind with automatic weights to an Armature. I have another model with particle system with Vertex group_(Hairs). So, I want both Vertex groups - previous one_(with automatic weights) and one with_(particle system).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To copy the vertex group of an object that is exactly the same, give your object a *Data Transfer* modifier, *Source* > object with the hair vertex group, *Mix Mode > Add*, enable *Vertex Data* and *Vertex Groups*, *Mapping >Topology*, click on *Generate Data Layer* and apply the modifier. Now the object should have inherited the hair vertex group.

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. This is working properly as i want.

Comment: Great! You're welcome  ;)